# Pass php array into HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to pass php variable into html for further processing.
this is php variable-

```
$coords   = array();

array_push($coords,some value);
```

I want to pass this to html-

```
var Coordinates = [];
Coordinates.push('<? php $coords; ?>');
```

But this is not the correct way as it gives error. Someone please help me to achieve this

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get a php-array to javascript you should do this through an ajax-call to your php-script.

Comment: SO is not a code design or debugging service. What have you tried? What error message? What research have you done? Please see [ask].

Comment: ?? Coordinates.push('<?php echo $coords; ?>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

`Coordinates.push('<?="[".implode($coords,",")."]" ?>');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 4):

The simplest example is to json_encode this out into the javascript var like so:

```
var Coordinates = <?= json_encode($coords) ?>
```

Then simply loop through this like you would any other json.

This question has been asked alot of times before however, so please check here for any further methods.

[How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: i have flagged this already as can be seen in the comments.

Comment: Right. Don't post an answer cause when this Q is closed, it will remain dead. :)

Comment: I posted this to bring notoriety to the previous thread. I have no problem with this answer being frozen out.

Comment: But hey, at least your answer is legit... the others are a joke.

Comment: People just trying to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

Server side, you can create a javascript array directly in your rendered html :

```
<script>
    var Coordinates = [<?php
        echo '"'.implode('","', $coords).'"';
    ?>];
</script>
```